# Searching for formula to align submenus direction in menu along the width

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, alignment, submenu

Currently I'm trying to achieve this

[image: submenus aligning]

With this: http://jsfiddle.net/EJXNV/3/

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>    
</li>
<li><a href="">Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>    
</li>
<li><a href="">Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

JS:

```
var coef = 7.5;

$("div > ul > li").each(function () {
$(this).children("ul").css("left", 
                       ($(this).position().left 
                       / coef) 
                       * (-1));
 });
```

But I can't figure out from where I should took that coefficient = 7.5 (I've got it empirically).

Please, help me to find out what formula I should use to get this coefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out it by myself:

```
$("div > ul > li").each(function () {
var coef = $("div > ul > li").last().position().left / ($(this).children("ul").width() -  $(this).width());
$(this).children("ul").css("left", ($(this).position().left / coef) * (-1));
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EJXNV/4/

Works with any width of any element (except the container, it must be fixed width and relative).